# no package when using "yum install tor"

Tags: tor-install

Last day ,I buy the vsp service. but there are no package when using "yum install tor" .

It worked when I use vmware locally.

epel has been installed already by :yum install epel-release

why I got differente result .

Comment: Try a 'yum update' first.

Answer (score 0):

resolve it :

I tried rpm to install it .

find the right rpm package to wget from the url:
http://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel